# Search <TAG> in Unix using grep command

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to exeucute following command

```
while read  line
do
var=`cat ids_acct_acct_tda_20131102.dat|grep  <$line>|wc -l`
echo " $var"
done < "m_field1.txt"
```

It resolves $line and showing error as resolved value $line is not file or directory.

It actually shows total count of line numbers.

what is error...?

Answer (score 1):

> It resolves $line and showing error as resolved value $line is not
>   file or directory.

You need to quote the pattern:

```
grep "<$line>"
```

When you say:

```
grep <$line>
```

the `<` and `>` are interpreted as redirection operators.

---

The following lines:

```
var=`cat ids_acct_acct_tda_20131102.dat|grep  <$line>|wc -l`
echo " $var"
```

could be written as:

```
grep -c "<${line}>" ids_acct_acct_tda_20131102.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the $line in single quotes to avoid the angle brackets being considered as redirection ops.

```
var=`cat ids_acct_acct_tda_20131102.dat|grep  '<$line>'|wc -l`
```